# When using sum, case and negate value, I get doubled value back

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, case

When trying to use sum function I the get wrong values while using CASE and negate values and I can't figure out why. (The negated value gets two times subtracted).

My goal is it where the type c_calcType is 'calcCorrection' to subtract it from the sum/groupBy.

When using:

```
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN c_calcType = 'calcCorrection' THEN (c_calcValue * -1)
                ELSE c_calcValue END) as c_calcValue,
       c_parentID
FROM DB_Calc
WHERE c_parentID is not null AND c_state <> 'deactiveted'
GROUP BY c_parentID
```

I get as value (c_calcValue) back 500, but I am excepting 750. When filtering and doing manual calculation I come to correct value.

The table as example looks like this:

| c_calcvalue | c_parentID | c_calcType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 5 | None |
| 250 | 5 | calcCorrection |

Strangely if say `WHERE c_ParentID = 5 AND c_calcType = 'calcCorrection'` I get the -250 back or if I say in the THEN Expression (THEN 0 else c_calcValue) the sum is also correct.

Comment: You should try to replicate this in a db<>fiddle.  For the data you have provided, the results should be what you expect.  In addition, your query refers to columns that are not in your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

First validate the subquery and try the approach,

Try converting to number before summation at selecting:

```
SELECT (CASE
                 WHEN c_calcType = 'calcCorrection' THEN (CONVERT(c_calcValue, INT)  * -1)
                 ELSE CONVERT(c_calcValue, INT)
              END)
                AS c_calcValue,
             c_parentID
        FROM DB_Calc
       WHERE c_parentID IS NOT NULL AND c_state <> 'deactiveted'
```

If Valid try the following:

```
  SELECT SUM (cValTable.c_calcValue), cValTable.c_parentID
       FROM (SELECT (CASE
                 WHEN c_calcType = 'calcCorrection' THEN (CONVERT(c_calcValue, INT)* -1)
                 ELSE CONVERT(c_calcValue, INT)
              END)
                AS c_calcValue,
             c_parentID
        FROM DB_Calc
       WHERE c_parentID IS NOT NULL AND c_state <> 'deactiveted') cValTable
    GROUP BY cValTable.c_parentID
```

Comment: I validated the query and the values are all good, if manual calculate all negative values togehter i get my -250, but if i try your secound query it still get -500 subtracted. I am going nuts

Comment: Try convert to integer like the edited answer @RekeUnhs

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your query is correct for the data you showed, but you may have data that you don't expect.

Having

```sql
CREATE TABLE DB_Calc (
  c_calcvalue int NOT NULL,
  c_calcType varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (c_calcvalue,c_calcType)
) 
INSERT INTO DB_Calc (c_calcvalue, c_calcType) VALUES
  (1000, 'None'),
  (250, 'calcCorrection');
```

the following SELECT

```
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN c_calcType = 'calcCorrection' THEN (c_calcValue * -1)
                ELSE c_calcValue END) as c_calcValue
FROM DB_Calc
```

produces 750:

```
c_calcValue
750
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c04c7/2/0).

I agree with M.Ghandour that you should first validate your source data before doing the SUM.

Comment: same result here since we didn't know the full data schema is but I believe the problem is in the `where` clause which might get other rows unexpected.

Comment: Sry if i cant show the real table, i tried everything to reproduce this but with no result (Adding Empty values or null values) only if i say THEN 0, i get the correct value back

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is causing this, but my bypass resultion is just for now seperate the calcCorrection into two query's and use union all.

```
SELECT sum(c_calcValue),c_parentID FROM DBCalc WHERE r_Rechnungstyp <> 'calcCorrection' AND c_state <> 'deactiveted' GROUP BY c_parentID UNION ALL SELECT sum(-c_calcValue),c_parentID FROM DBCalc WHERE r_Rechnungstyp = 'calcCorrection' AND c_state <> 'deactiveted' GROUP BY c_parentID
```